# IE not displaying span inside an a tag correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I tried to show this in jsfiddle, but not sure how to include the image, so hoping this is clear from just the code.  I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="tableview tableview-links results">
        <li>
      <a href="#search/1" class="pad-top has-popover js-show" data-container="body">
        <div class="story">
          <span class="metadata inline-block">
            <span class="link-text">Some Text</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#search/1" class="detail-disclosure has-popover js-show" data-container="body" >
        <span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the following css:

```
.tableview-links li>a.detail-disclosure span
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 29px;
    height: 31px;
    background: transparent url(images/detail-disclosure-button.png);
    -webkit-background-size: 58px 31px;
    -moz-background-size: 58px 31px;
    -ms-background-size: 58px 31px;
    -o-background-size: 58px 31px;
    background-size: 58px 31px;
}
```

The image associated w/the detail-disclosure span shows up correctly in chrome/firefox inside the `<li>` element and to the right of "Some Text", but in IE, it shows up outside and on the following line.

Is there any way to fix make this work in IE, and, barring that, any way to just not display it in IE?  I tried setting it to display:none in the css file and then moving this css block to an <-- if !IE--> block after the css link, but that hides it in both IE and other browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the full public URL to your image in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Two questions: What's your IE version? Did you also define the div.story tag as inline-block? It is not good to include a block element(div) inside an inline element(a tag).

Comment: Off topic, but I don't like the slash in the href. I mean, you'd end up in a URL looking like `/path/file#search/1`, is that guaranteed to work in all cases?

Comment: @Mr Lister - it's a single page backbone app - it's just the way it works

Comment: @Barmar - the image is not public - only on a dev machine

Comment: @Sho, my IE version is 10, but I've tried emulating different versions and it is the same

Comment: Upload the image to a public site, like imageshack.

Comment: @Barmar - didn't want to register just for this, but it's a good thought.  Anyway, decided just to hide the image part in IE - it's not that important.  Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@sydneyos, thanks. Could you please try set the div.story to inline-block?

I don't have a windows machine, so I can't test.

Or if you would like to apply some special css for IE, please have a look at the following example:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie ie7 lte7 lte8 lte9" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="no-js ie ie8 lte8 lte9" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="no-js ie ie9 lte9>" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

The <-- if !IE--> should not work in many browsers, I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, setting div.story to a span or inline-block does not make a difference, and I guess IE10 doesn't respect the conditionals, so I can't change the display behavior for that, though even in IE9 mode, it didn't seem to work.

Comment: IE... Have no idea. your span width is 29, and background image width is 58. Does this matter?

Comment: Yeah, it's a great thought, but no, that's actually by design - if I make the span width match the image width, I get a double image.